# Combine different regex together in xargs command

Tags: regex, perl, bash

I have these two regexes:

```
find ... | xargs perl -pi -e 's/\t/    /g'
find ... | xargs perl -pi -e 's/[^\S\n]+$//g'
```

First one changes tabs to 4 spaces, and second removes any trailing white space at the end of each line.

I am tempted to combine the two, but don't want to break something.  Besides, they are doing different things -- one is adding spaces, another is removing spaces.  Is there a safe way to merge these two together or just leave them as is?

Comment: Technically, the second substitution removes trailing whitespace *except for newlines* (newlines are a type of whitespace).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
find ... | xargs perl -l -pi -e 's/\t/    /g; s/\s+$//'
```

Since the second `find` is operating on the results of the first one, it's safe to perform each command in succession in a single `perl` invocation.

Comment: by the way, `/\s+$//g` removes all line endings and mushes my files into one line.  That's why I used the `[^\S\n]`.  I understand that  here that regex operates on entire file rather than on per-line basis

Comment: you could do `... perl -pi -le ...` to make it work with the `\s` version, but easier just to have not changed it from the correct `[^\S\n]`.  (-l has the side effect of adding newlines to the ends of files that are missing them.)

Comment: Actually, it just operates on lines. I'm used to operating on lines after calling `chomp`, and then adding back the newline when printing, and forgot that the -p option doesn't do that. The `-l` option achieves this.

Comment: Re "-l has the side effect of adding newlines to the ends of files that are missing them.", That would be quite appropriate given the goal is whitespace normalization.

Comment: Why do you need -l option.

Comment: @justintime That option removes the newline from the input before processing it, and then adds it back when printing the updated line. Otherwise, the newlines are removed by `s/\s+$//` and all the lines get smushed together.

Answer (score 4):

I would leave the expressions separate, but you can perform them both with a single call to perl:

```
find ... | xargs perl -pi -e 's/\t/    /g;' -e 's/[^\S\n]+$//g;'
```

Comment: @mpapec You need to include a semi-colon at the end of each expression: `perl -pi -e 's///;' -e 's///;'`